Reading a book with multiple endnotes
As a doctoral student in an interdisciplinary field, I come across a number of books that mention multiple 'endnotes' (as opposed to footnotes). I have no particular way of reading such books, but sometimes, dabbling between the main text and the Notes section at the back of the book becomes cumbersome and disrupts the rhythm of reading. Conversely, trying to read the notes once I finish the chapter, or the book, seems a bit out of place. I would appreciate if you could suggest efficient ways to read books out of your own experiences.

I personally find extensive backnotes (endnotes) painful as you suggest. There are different strategies, depending on what you'd rather do and somewhat on the material.

Ignore the backnotes.

Use a bookmark for your current reading position and another for the current backnote and page back and forth. (I often use this)

Read the notes later, as needed.

Read the material twice (at least), employing 1. on the first reading and 2. on the second.


If the material is only peripherally useful to you then 1. might suffice. But if you really need to know the material, either 2. or 4. might be needed. With 4, the first reading gives you a good overview and the second provides what may be needed detail.
But it is a personal choice, influenced by the importance of the material.
And, extensive footnotes can be painful also. Note that including all that material inline would probably be worse, making reading even more difficult.

Thanks for the suggestions @Buffy! I have tried 2, and 3 before on different occasions, but each strategy after some time starts to pain! Of course, 1 is not helpful either as I feel like I am missing out on some crucial information. I will try 4 now! :)

And if electronic, having two separate windows on two separate monitors is a big help.


Photocopy (or print out) the endnotes section, and keep it handy while you read.  I have found this strategy to be quite useful (though it has been 20 years since I've tried to read a book with endnotes---switching to mathematics may have been the smartest decision of my undergraduate career in that respect). :D


In addition to Jon Custer's and Xander Henderson's suggestions, when I read a (hardcopy) book with endnotes (I've read books in which at least 20% of the pages are endnotes), I put a sticky note at the top of the endnote page corresponding to where I'm at in the text and use that to "thumb back to an endnote" as they appear. I've always thought it would be nice to use to different notations for endnotes so as to distinguish those that only cite the source of something and those that (either in addition to or instead of a source) actually give useful or interesting tangential commentary.

All are very helpful suggestions. Thank you, @Jon, Xander, and Dave! It would be so much easier if readers are made aware of such particularities, I agree, Dave!

A basic rule for authors (see Chicago Manual of Style) is to avoid long or unnecessary endnotes or footnotes. If it's important, put it in the main text. If it's not that important, consider whether you need a note at all. Given this basic rule, you're not obligated to continually interrupt your reading to go to the endnotes. You can have some confidence that you might not be missing much if you don't read the notes. You could check the endnotes if there's something you're especially curious about.

It can be worth checking a few of the notes to get a sense of how important they are. Especially since a reader may be interested in something the author did not consider all that important for the point they were making.
